# Receiving Push Notifications on Swift with AWS Mobile Hub

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3, apple-push-notifications

I am currently developing and iOS app using Swift, which I am new to, and the code generated from AWS Mobile Hub, with AWS SNS to register devices and send notifications.

On my class **AWSMobileClient** I have the following code:

```
func didFinishLaunching(_ application: UIApplication, withOptions launchOptions: [AnyHashable: Any]?) -> Bool {

    print("didFinishLaunching:")

    // Register the sign in provider instances with their unique identifier
    AWSSignInProviderFactory.sharedInstance().register(signInProvider: AWSFacebookSignInProvider.sharedInstance(), forKey: AWSFacebookSignInProviderKey)


    var didFinishLaunching: Bool = AWSIdentityManager.default().interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    didFinishLaunching = didFinishLaunching && AWSPushManager(forKey: ServiceKey).interceptApplication(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    if (!isInitialized) {
        AWSIdentityManager.default().resumeSession(completionHandler: { (result: Any?, error: Error?) in
            print("Result: \(result) \n Error:\(error)")
        }) // If you get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS here in iOS Simulator, then do Simulator -> "Reset Content and Settings..."
        // This will clear bad auth tokens stored by other apps with the same bundle ID.
        isInitialized = true
    }

    return didFinishLaunching
}
```

Which is called normally.

On my AppDelegate, I have the following:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance.application(application, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: deviceToken)

        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: AWSMobileClient.remoteNotificationKey), object: deviceToken)
        print("###--- DID REGISTER FOR REMOTE NOTIFICATION ---###")
    }
```

Which is also called.

However, when I try sending a notification using AWS SNS, my function:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

    print("###--- DID RECEIVE REMOTE NOTIFICATION ---###")

    AWSMobileClient.sharedInstance.application(application, didReceiveRemoteNotification: userInfo , fetchCompletionHandler: completionHandler)

    // This is where you intercept push notifications.
    if (application.applicationState == .active) {
        UIAlertView.init(title: "Notification Received", message: userInfo.description, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }
}
```

Is never called.

Looking for a solution I read that since iOS 10 there are some chances that need to be made to deal with push notification, but I'm not sure about the correct ways.

How should I implement the code to receive the notifications?

Comment: Did you follow [these steps](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/getting-started-step-5-adding-push-notifications.html)?  They involve uploading your Universial Apple certificate to AWS and getting your IAM Policy correct.

Comment: Hi, @Taterhead. Yes, the apple certificate is correct as is the IAM Policy.

Comment: are push notifications turned on in 'Capabilities'?

Comment: @donkon yes, they are. I receive the confirmation in didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, but when I send a push notification, didReceiveRemoteNotification is never called.

Comment: Did you ever get this working?  If so what was the issue?

Comment: @KevinR I wasn't able to get this working. Going to get back to the project in the near future and test again.

Comment: @filipebarretto, OK let us know.  Thanks, Kevin